# How Do I Delay a Bodymovin Animation

Tags: javascript, bodymovin

Ok so I just started using bodymovin and was wondering if there was a way for me to delay the animation.

My web page fades in so during that fade in the animation is happening which is not what i would like. So if I could delay it by 2 seconds that would be great.

Here is my code:

```
var animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
container: document.getElementById('bm'),
renderer: 'svg',
loop: false,
autoplay: true,
path: 'data.json'

})
```

I have tried to use setTimeout but I have not been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set the `autoplay` value to `false`, and call `play()` in a timeout of 2000ms. I'm assuming you're using the library found [here](http://airbnb.io/lottie/web/getting-started.html).

```
var animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
  container: document.getElementById('bm'),
  renderer: 'svg',
  loop: false,
  autoplay: false,
  path: 'data.json'
})

setTimeout(function(){ animation.play(); }, 2000);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! All of the answers I was getting from the Lottie Github page were so confusing! lol